# Required true with condition clause is not working in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose. So in one of my schema , i want to set required field true only if a particular field satisfies a condition. So i have written a function to set a required field true only if the condition is true. But required flag is being true even if the condition is wrong. Even the console inside the function is not being executed. What am i doing wrong?  Thanks in advance

This my schema

```
var ApplicationsSchema = new Schema({

  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: function(value) {
        console.log('inside function')
        console.log(this.status)
         return this.status === 'submit';
     },
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in the name of the Organization']
    },
     last_name: {
       type: String,
       validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in the     name of the Organization']
     },
     phone_number: {
       type: String,
       validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in the phone number']
   },
    status:{
   type: String,
   }
});

mongoose.model('Applications', ApplicationsSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of the validating required field like this, you could add custom validation which will work only if your selected field is stetted. In that case, your model would look like

```
var ApplicationsSchema = new Schema({

first_name: {
    type: String,
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in the name of the Organization']
},
 last_name: {
    type: String,
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in the     name of the Organization']
 },
 phone_number: {
     type: String,
     validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in the phone number']
 },
   status:{
     type: String,
 }
});

ApplicationSchema.pre('validate', function(next){
   let _this = this;
   if(_this.status === 'submit' && !_this.first_name) { //status is submit and first name is not present -> error
      _this.invalidate("first_name", "First name is required");
      return next("first_name");
} else { // no error
    next()
}

});

mongoose.model('Applications', ApplicationsSchema);
```

Comment: let me try..  but here the problem is that i have to apply this required  field to all the fields. Then i have add the condition of all the fields

Comment: yes. It is working for me. But how to implement this for all  fields

Comment: In that case I don't know the solution. Maybe you can add validation on the server side code, before even trying to go in database.

Comment: i did it in the server side code.  Please edit the return next("firstName"); field   to return next(first_name);  I think it is typo error